# App Icon is not showing In Tablet?

Tags: android

I changed the default `ic_launcher` icon with my app icon in all the res folders in the project. When I test it on my GNexus, my icon is there. However, when I run it on my GTab10.1, the default icon (the green robot) shows instead! I'm sure I deleted this icon from the entire project.

Is this a caching issue? How can I solve it?

---

Update:

In my Tab, when I go to `Manage Application > Application Info` , I see my icon there and not the default one! This is REALLY strange!

Comment: I suspect it has to do with your tablet. Did you completely remove the app from your tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Project > Clean...` was enough to bring my icon back! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure in manifest file  icon used as you set with new name and make project clean